# How quickly does the bonus pool refill?

Tags: starcraft-2

In SC2, how fast do my bonus pool points refill?  I have finally worn my pool down to 0.  Does anybody know if it is just time that refills them or something else?

Comment: Deleting my answer.  It does not help you.  I did find this Team Liquid link: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=118212 which was made in April so during the beta.  There is a section on the bonus pool there.  "1 point every 2" hours caught my eye.

Comment: I had 13 points in my bonus pool (2v2 if that matters) when my last played was 19 hours ago, so 1 point every 2 seems like it may be a bit off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to original research by our friends at [teamliquid](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=118212):

> The Bonus Pool accrues at a rate of 1 point per 2 hours, whether the player or team is active or not. The Bonus Pool also begins building based on when the ladder season began. That is, if Player A was placed into a division and started with a Bonus Pool of 100, then 24 hours later Player B placed into a new division, Player B's Bonus Pool would be 112.

This means it does not matter when you join the ladder your bonus pool will be as if you joined at the start of the season.

You'll notice this was last updated August 11th

Answer (score 1):

The bonus pool for 1v1 matches and the random team leagues grows by one point per two hours, as tzenes points out in his answer.

The non-random team leagues (where you play with a fixed team) have a slower growing bonus pool, at least in the current (the second) season. The bonus pool for 2v2 teams grows only by one point every three hours, and the bonus pool for 3v3 and 4v4 teams only increases by one point every six hours.

The reason for these lower increases is probably that fixed teams usually don't play as often. A single player can always start a game whenever he feels like it, but for a team all members have to be online. If teams would get the same bonus pool as single players, most of the teams probably wouldn't be able to deplete the pool.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: At what rate does the Bonus Pool grows?
>
> A: For Grandmaster and Master league player, the bonus pool increase at the rate of 56 minutes per 1 bonus pool, equivalent to 180 bonus pool per week.
>
> For Bronze to Diamond league player, the bonus pool increase at the rate of 96 minutes 3 seconds per 1 bonus pool, equivalent to 104.4 bonus pool per week.

[Source](http://starcraft2procoaching.weebly.com/blog/bonus-pool)